# Petition Error "Oops. It looks like there is no response option configured."

Tags: civicampaign, civimobile, petition

I'm trying to set up door-to-door canvassing capabilities using CiviCampaign and CiviMobile.  I've set up a Campaign; I created some custom fields like Knock Result (Home, Not Home, etc); I created a Profile with all the contact fields fields and custom fields; I created a page in WordPress that displays the Profile / Form; I created a Petition under CiviCampaign that uses the Profile I set up; I reserved a few respondents for myself; I search for a respondent and choose the action
"record petition signature responses" and I get the error "Oops. It looks like there is no response option configured."  I looked at CiviCampaign Component Settings and set up a group Petition Contacts and a Tag called Unconfirmed, but no joy. I tried setting up a survey and ran into the same thing. What don't I understand...thanks!
WordPress and CiviCRM 5.37.2

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what specifically fixed this problem, but I gave the CiviMobile folks access to my test domain and it went away.  It went away rather mysteriously, but they gave me some good tips on surveys and petitions.